# Filter a list has one keystroke lag in React

Tags: reactjs, state, filtering

I'm trying to do a simple Filter component that filter a list with an input.

The problem is the rendering of the list has one keystroke lag.

For exemple :
I type an 'a'
Nothing change
I type another 'a' so the filter looks like "aa"
The list is filtered on the previous state of the String "a"

I know that the setState is asynchronous but I don't know how to do with good practices.

index.js

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

App.js

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Filter = ({ countries, setCountriesToShow }) => {
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState("");

  const handleOnChangeEvent = (e) => {
    setFilter(e.target.value);
    setCountriesToShow(
      countries.filter((country) => {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter.toLowerCase());
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      find countries
      <input onChange={handleOnChangeEvent} />
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [countries, setCountries] = useState([]);
  const [countriesToShow, setCountriesToShow] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setCountries(response.data);
      setCountriesToShow(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Filter countries={countries} setCountriesToShow={setCountriesToShow} />
      {countriesToShow.map((country) => {
        return <li key={country.name}>{country.name}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Instead of duplicating the state, save the input value in the `App` component and filter the countries when rendering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

state updates don't reflect immediately. So when you are trying to filter, use the input that is received from the input element instead of from the state

```
const handleOnChangeEvent = (e) => {
    const newFilter = e.target.value;
    setFilter(newFilter);
    setCountriesToShow(
      countries.filter((country) => {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(newfilter.toLowerCase());
      })
    );
  };
```

Another way to implement it is to make use of useEffect

```
const handleOnChangeEvent = (e) => {
    const newFilter = e.target.value;
    setFilter(newFilter);
  };
useEffect(() => {
   setCountriesToShow(
      countries.filter((country) => {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().startsWith(filter.toLowerCase());
      })
    );
}, [filter]);
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Everything works now, is this good to set a filter State inside the Filter component ? It's useless so ?

Comment: Yes you can remove that since you don't implement a controlled input

Comment: Ok, what is the best practice ? useEffect or store the filter value inside a variable ? (I wait the timeout and mark ur answer as response)

Comment: It is better to use the filter value if there is only once source of updating a filter, if there are multiple sources, useEffect will serve you better